# Apple Cider vs Apple Juice Chemical/Physical Properties in Relation to Milk

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

Why does non-alcoholic apple cider mix smoothly with milk, but mixing apple juice with milk causes it to curdle?

Answer (score 0):

Apple juice contains organic acids which causes the proteins present in milk to coagulate (curdle). The non-alcoholic cider most likely (depends on the brand?) contains less acids, so there is no coagulation. Good thing you mentioned that there is no alcohol present in the cider - ethanol is another thing that can cause milk to curdle.